# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in Linq statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
var surveyResultItem = _mcniDbContext.SurveyResultsLines.Where(e => e.SurveyOptionId == deleteOption.SurveyOptionId).ToList();
```

Where my Dbmodel is `_mcniDbContext` and `SurveyResultsLines`  is my classin it. I have checked that value is not null for deleteOption and SurveyOptionId is present in both of them. There no red line in my code but while running it. it gives error:

> Error Message:    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

> Exception Trace:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an > object.
> at MCNIDev.Processor.Services.SurveyProcessor.CheckSurveyResultsLines(SurveyQuestions deleteQuestion, SurveyOptions deleteOption) in D:\Projects\mcninew\MCNIDev\MCNIDev\Processor\Services\SurveyProcessor.cs:line 383

Comment: "*I have checked that value is not null*" -- what exactly have you checked

Comment: By applying break points. and i have this statement before it " if (deleteOption != null)". I also passes this code but still shows the error

Comment: @AnirudhRawat What if `_mcniDbContext` is `null`, or `SurveyResultsLines` is `null`, or an element (represented by `e`) in that list is `null`?